# Servidor apache reconoce php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll pero no php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

Tags: php, apache

Buen día, tengo el siguiente problema: tengo instalada la versión de **`Xampp 3.2.2`** para **`apache 5.6.38`**, en el archivo **`php.ini`** agregué las extensiones

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

y en la carpeta **`c:\xampp\php\ext`** están efectivamente los archivos

```
php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

también me aseguré que en **`php.ini`** este bien configurado la ruta en donde tengo mis dlls

```
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
```

Ahora bien, generé un archivo php para ejecutar lo siguiente

```
print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
phpinfo();
```

Al cargar la página php con esas líneas, me detecta el driver

```
Array
(
    [0] => sqlsrv
)
```

el problema es que phpinfo, solo me muestra información respecto al **`php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts`** en la sección de PDO, pero no aparece nada respecto a **`php_sqlsrv_56_ts;`** con los otros drivers que pongo si me muestra info, como ser el de curl, sqlite o mysql.

Probé con otras versiones de drivers de sql y ni siquiera me detecta el PDO, y verifiqué que la versión de drivers sea la correcta para php 5.6.38.

A pesar de detectar el PDO cuando quiero usar una conexión a BD de SQL, me arroja el siguiente error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

Alguna idea de que puede estar pasando???

Comment: Tenes algún error en el log de php? Por otro lado las versiones que bajaste son para los bits de tu procesador no? (32 / 64)

Comment: Tienes que descargar el add de Windows